# How to install IIS Server and Hosting bundle in quick succession without running into errors?

Tags: windows, powershell, .net-core, iis, windows-server

If I install the IIS Server and Hosting bundle in quick succession like this (on a new Windows 10 Server):

```bash
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools

# Ignore the next line for now, its my current workaround
Start-Sleep -Seconds 120

Write-Host "-- Installing Dotnet Hosting Bundle"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
$tempDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
$downloadPath = "$tempdir\netCoreHostingBundle.exe";
$DefaultProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;

$securityProtocol = @();
$securityProtocol += [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol;
$securityProtocol += [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $securityProtocol;
$WebClient = New-Object Net.WebClient; 

$Uri = 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/0d000d1b-89a4-4593-9708-eb5177777c64/cfb3d74447ac78defb1b66fd9b3f38e0/dotnet-hosting-6.0.6-win.exe';
if ($DefaultProxy -and (-not $DefaultProxy.IsBypassed($Uri))) { $WebClient.Proxy = New-Object Net.WebProxy($DefaultProxy.GetProxy($Uri).OriginalString, $True); };
$WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $downloadPath);
 
$arguments = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
$arguments.Add("/quiet")
$arguments.Add("/norestart")
Start-Process -FilePath $downloadPath -ArgumentList $arguments -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru -WorkingDirectory $tempDir

Write-Host "-- Restarting IIS"
Stop-Service W3SVC
Start-Service W3SVC
Get-Service W3SVC
```

Everything works out fine from the installation point of view. But if I run a NET Core Application in IIS the following error occurs:

[HTTP Error 500.19 - HRESULT code 0x8007000d](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage)

Googling around [this happens when "Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS". The simple solution is written in the next sentence: "the bundle installation must be repaired"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle) and indeed this works.

The Question being now:

- How do I avert the situation altogether?
- or How do I wait till IIS is really installed, so it is safe to install the Hosting Bundle?

Comment: Can you verify the features are installed/enabled via `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature` https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/may/25/automating-iis-feature-installation-with-powershell before moving on to install the hosting bundle?

Answer (score 0):

> If the Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation
> must be repaired. Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after
> installing IIS.

This is the method I found in another site:

> Use a custom action that enables IIS before the installation of ".NET
> Core IIS Hosting" prerequisite.

For example, you can add a custom action as a non-sequential custom action (so it can be triggered from a UI control) and then schedule it in the "Dialogs" page --> "Pre-install UI" --> "WelcomePrereqDlg" dialog --> "Next" button. This will enable IIS before installing the prerequisites.

The method comes from this link: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44696

Comment: I am not using advanced installer, so I am looking for a Powershell solution.

Comment: All right, if this is possible, hope you can share here.